# How to catch PermissionDenied exception in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, exception, django-rest-framework

If a particular DRF `APIView` view requires uses `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`, how do I catch and handle a `PermissionDenied` exception for when a user can not be authenticated?

Here is my `ExampleView` as is right now:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(request.user)
```

As of now if a user can not be authenticated this view just throws an error. How can I catch it and return something different when that error occurs?

Comment: Can you share the code in render?

Comment: @KanishkAnand I have updated question

Comment: You can try like: value={{user:this.state.user}}

Comment: JSON is a text format, like XML or CSV. Once you're in JavaScript, you're dealing with JavaScript objects.

Comment: looks like the problem is in render. You can't print an entire object there, you need a primitive (string, number, bool, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to alter the style of the response, you could write the following custom exception handler:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Handle PermissionDenied
    if isinstance(exc, PermissionDenied):
        return custom_response()

    return response
```

Then, in your `settings.py`, you need to configure DRF to use this handler:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

More info in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, isn't there a more direct way of doing this directly inside the view?

Comment: it happens before it reaches the view